# Can node.js wait for browser feedback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on an image program that uses html canvas to do some pixel effects, and then compresses the final output with [libBPG](https://bellard.org/bpg/).

I use both of the programs like this:

---

Step 1) Run a html file that has code to call a jpg.

Step 2) The code manipulates the image and saves it automatically to the same folder of the html file using file-saver.js.

Step 3) I then use a command line interface to compress it with the bpg library. An example command would look like this:

```
$ bpg (path_to_html_folder)/modified.jpg
```

Which saves the output as *modified.bpg* to the bpg parent folder.

---

Is there anyway to use node.js or some other command line tool to listen for when the browser saves the image as "modified.jpg" to it's folder, and then automatically invoke the 'bpg' command instead of me having to do it manually?

Thank you for any help you can offer!

Comment: How about a folder watch?

Comment: use a script file?